# Issue to use pybind11 in Visual Studio 2022 to wrap a c++ function that takes an eigen::MatrixXd as input

Tags: python, c++, windows, visual-studio, pybind11

I am having an issue trying to wrap a C++ function using pybind11 in Visual Studio 2022, I have been able to replicate [example provided by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/working-with-c-cpp-python-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022). However, now I am trying to wrap up my own function, which uses the eigen library. I can built the library, however, when I try to install it in my python virtual environment I get an error, below you can see the output at the Command Prompt in VS.

> ### ----- Installing 'C:\Users\e552e887\Desktop\VisualStudioProjects\multMatrix\multcpp'
> ----- Processing c:\users\e552e887\desktop\visualstudioprojects\multmatrix\multcpp
> Installing build dependencies: started   Installing build
> dependencies: finished with status 'done'   Getting requirements to
> build wheel: started   Getting requirements to build wheel: finished
> with status 'done'   Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
> Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
> Building wheels for collected packages: multcpp   Building wheel for
> multcpp (pyproject.toml): started   Building wheel for multcpp
> (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'   error:
> subprocess-exited-with-error
> Building wheel for multcpp (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.   exit code: 1
> [35 lines of output]   running bdist_wheel   running build   running build_ext   building 'multcpp' extension   "C:\Program
> Files\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe"
> /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Iinclude
> -IC:\Users\e552e887\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-i52hlh1c\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include
> -IC:\Users\e552e887\Desktop\VisualStudioProjects\multMatrix\multMatrix\cpp_to_python_env\include
> -IC:\Users\e552e887\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\include -IC:\Users\e552e887\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Include "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\ATLMFC\include"
> "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include" "-IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files
> (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files
> (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt"
> "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
> Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpmodule.cpp
> /Fobuild\temp.win32-cpython-38\Release\module.obj -std=c++11
> -stdlib=libc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.7   cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=c++11'   cl : Command line
> warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-stdlib=libc++'   cl :
> Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option
> '-mmacosx-version-min=10.7'   module.cpp
> C:\Users\e552e887\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-i52hlh1c\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include\pybind11/eigen.h(532):
> warning C4316: 'Eigen::Ref<const
> Eigen::Matrix4d,0,Eigen::OuterStride<-1>>': object allocated on the
> heap may not be aligned 16
> C:\Users\e552e887\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-i52hlh1c\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include\pybind11/eigen.h(481):
> note: while compiling class template member function 'bool
> pybind11::detail::type_caster<Eigen::Ref<const
> Eigen::Matrix4d,0,Eigen::OuterStride<-1>>,void>::load(pybind11::handle,bool)'
> C:\Users\e552e887\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-i52hlh1c\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include\pybind11\cast.h(1430):
> note: see reference to function template instantiation 'bool
> pybind11::detail::type_caster<Eigen::Ref<const
> Eigen::Matrix4d,0,Eigen::OuterStride<-1>>,void>::load(pybind11::handle,bool)'
> being compiled
> C:\Users\e552e887\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-i52hlh1c\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include\pybind11\cast.h(1402):
> note: see reference to class template instantiation
> 'pybind11::detail::type_caster<Eigen::Ref<const
> Eigen::Matrix4d,0,Eigen::OuterStride<-1>>,void>' being compiled
> C:\Users\e552e887\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-i52hlh1c\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include\pybind11/pybind11.h(220):
> note: see reference to class template instantiation
> 'pybind11::detail::argument_loader<const Eigen::Ref<const
> Eigen::Matrix4d,0,Eigen::OuterStride<-1>> &>' being compiled
> C:\Users\e552e887\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-i52hlh1c\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include\pybind11/pybind11.h(91):
> note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void
> pybind11::cpp_function::initialize<Return(__cdecl *&)(const
> Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix4d,0,Eigen::OuterStride<-1>>
> &),Return,const Eigen::Ref<const
> Eigen::Matrix4d,0,Eigen::OuterStride<-1>>&,pybind11::name,pybind11::scope,pybind11::sibling,char[86]>(Func,Return
> (__cdecl *)(const Eigen::Ref<const
> Eigen::Matrix4d,0,Eigen::OuterStride<-1>> &),const pybind11::name
> &,const pybind11::scope &,const pybind11::sibling &,const char
> (&)[86])' being compiled
> with
> [
> Return=Eigen::Matrix4d,
> Func=Eigen::Matrix4d (__cdecl *&)(const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix4d,0,Eigen::OuterStride<-1>> &)
> ]   C:\Users\e552e887\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-i52hlh1c\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include\pybind11/pybind11.h(1170):
> note: see reference to function template instantiation
> 'pybind11::cpp_function::cpp_function<Eigen::Matrix4d,const
> Eigen::Ref<const
> Eigen::Matrix4d,0,Eigen::OuterStride<-1>>&,pybind11::name,pybind11::scope,pybind11::sibling,char[86]>(Return
> (**cdecl *)(const Eigen::Ref<const
> Eigen::Matrix4d,0,Eigen::OuterStride<-1>> &),const pybind11::name
> &,const pybind11::scope &,const pybind11::sibling &,const char
> (&)[86])' being compiled
> with
> [
> Return=Eigen::Matrix4d Failed to build multcpp
> ]   module.cpp(14): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'pybind11::module*
> &pybind11::module*::def<Eigen::Matrix4d(__cdecl *)(const
> Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix4d,0,Eigen::OuterStride<-1>>
> &),char[86]>(const char *,Func &&,const char (&)[86])' being compiled
> with
> [
> Func=Eigen::Matrix4d (__cdecl *)(const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix4d,0,Eigen::OuterStride<-1>> &)
> ]   "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\bin\HostX86\x86\link.exe"
> /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2
> /MANIFESTUAC:NO
> /LIBPATH:C:\Users\e552e887\Desktop\VisualStudioProjects\multMatrix\multMatrix\cpp_to_python_env\libs
> /LIBPATH:C:\Users\e552e887\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\libs
> /LIBPATH:C:\Users\e552e887\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32
> /LIBPATH:C:\Users\e552e887\Desktop\VisualStudioProjects\multMatrix\multMatrix\cpp_to_python_env\PCbuild\win32
> "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\ATLMFC\lib\x86"
> "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\lib\x86"
> "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um\x86"
> "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
> Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\um\x86"
> /EXPORT:PyInit_multcpp build\temp.win32-cpython-38\Release\module.obj
> /OUT:build\lib.win32-cpython-38\multcpp.cp38-win32.pyd
> /IMPLIB:build\temp.win32-cpython-38\Release\multcpp.cp38-win32.lib
> Creating library build\temp.win32-cpython-38\Release\multcpp.cp38-win32.lib and object
> build\temp.win32-cpython-38\Release\multcpp.cp38-win32.exp
> module.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class
> Eigen::Matrix<double,4,4,0,4,4> __cdecl TransInv(class
> Eigen::Ref<class Eigen::Matrix<double,4,4,0,4,4> const ,0,class
> Eigen::OuterStride<-1> > const &)"
> (?TransInv@@YA?AV?$Matrix@N$03$03$0A@$03$03@Eigen@@ABV?$Ref@$$CBV?$Matrix@N$03$03$0A@$03$03@Eigen@@$0A@V?$OuterStride@$0?0@2@@2@@Z)
> build\lib.win32-cpython-38\multcpp.cp38-win32.pyd : fatal error
> LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   error: command 'C:\Program
> Files\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\bin\HostX86\x86\link.exe'
> failed with exit code 1120   [end of output]
> note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.   ERROR: Failed building wheel for multcpp ERROR:
> Could not build wheels for multcpp, which is required to install
> pyproject.toml-based projects
> ----- Failed to install 'C:\Users\e552e887\Desktop\VisualStudioProjects\multMatrix\multcpp'

My setup.py file looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension
import pybind11

cpp_args = ['-std=c++11', '-stdlib=libc++', '-mmacosx-version-min=10.7']

sfc_module = Extension(
    'multcpp',
    sources=['module.cpp'],
    include_dirs=['include', pybind11.get_include()],
    language='c++',
    extra_compile_args=cpp_args,
    )

setup(
    name='multcpp',
    version='1.0',
    description='Python package with superfastcode2 C++ extension (PyBind11)',
    ext_modules=[sfc_module],
)
```

The 'include' in include_dirs is the directory where the eigen folder is located.

The cpp-file that wrapper the function look like this:

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/eigen.h>
#include "mult_eigen.h"


int addFive(int a) {
    return a + 5; } namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(multcpp, m) {
    m.def("TransInv", &TransInv, R"pbdoc(
        Compute a hyperbolic tangent of a single argument expressed in radians.
    )pbdoc");
    m.def("addFive", &addFive, R"pbdoc(
        Compute a hyperbolic tangent of a single argument expressed in radians.
    )pbdoc");

#ifdef VERSION_INFO
    m.attr("__version__") = VERSION_INFO;
#else
    m.attr("__version__") = "dev";
#endif }
```

If anyone can help me solve this issue, I would really appreciate it. This is my first time trying to run a c++ function in Python.

Comment: Was the installation successful only with the sample [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/working-with-c-cpp-python-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022)  provided?

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT , I have tried installing other problems that do not contain the eigen library following the steps shown in the sample provided in the document. I think my issue is how the eigen library has been included. When I added a problem using the eigen library the compiler was complaining because it could not not found Eigen/Core, then I added the 'include' directory in the setup file that contains the eigen library, now, I am facing the problem shown.